# emacs nxhtml-mode[No match]

Tags: php, emacs, dot-emacs, carbon-emacs

I am having some problems with nxhtml installation, I want my .php files to look better and I don't wanna go back to netbeans...

I have downloaded nxhtml and I created a folder called 'emacs-packages' where my .emacs is
I added this line in my .emacs file :

```
(load "emacs-packages/nxhtml/autostart22.el")
```

whenever I try M-x nxhtml-mode I get [No Match] as an answer...

I also tried

```
(load "emacs-packages/nxhtml/autostart.el")
```

and I get an error on startup but since my version is 22 I think the first one is  more appropriate

are there any other packages I should install forst in order to use it?
what am I doing wrong?

I am using Carbon emacs 22.3.1 on MacOs

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved I just changed the load to load-file:

```
(load-file "emacs-packages/nxhtml/autostart.el")
```

this page here explains difference  [Link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_installing_packages.html)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need is

```
(load "emacs-packages/nxhtml/autostart.el")
```

Try to specify the full path. Put the cursor on `"emacs-packages/nxhtml/autostart.el"` and call M-x ffap to see if it can do `find-file-at-point`.

Comment: thank you, it seems to find the file...so if the path is correct and it's the only thing needed why do I get [No Match] ? maybe I don't use it right?how would I make it work?

Comment: I removed everything but this line (load "/usr/local/share/emacs/nxhtml/autostart.el") from my .emacs and it works. Try to do the same thing. Maybe you have some other package installed which prevents emacs from loading. Can you do M-x find-function nxhtml-mode ?

Comment: I can't even use find-function: "Possible completions are:"
1.find-function-at-point     2.find-function-on-key
3.find-function-other-frame    4.find-function-other-window